# Angular 6 - Property 'pwdMatchValidator' does not exist on type 'typeof CustomValidator'

Tags: angular

I get this compilation error:

> ERROR in src/app/modules/auth/pages/register/register.component.ts(38,24): error TS2339: Property **'pwdMatchValidator'** does not exist on type 'typeof CustomValidator'.

The code it refers to, is:

```
import { CustomValidator } from '@helpers/custom-validator';

...

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormGroup({
      first: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
      last: new FormControl(''),
    }),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    confirmed: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  }, CustomValidator.pwdMatchValidator);
}
```

I've declared `@helpers` in `tsconfig.json > compilerOptions > paths:

```
"paths": {
  ...
  "@helpers/*": ["./src/app/core/helpers/*"],
  ...
}
```

The `CustomValidator` class contains:

```
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

export class CustomValidator {

  static pwdMatchValidator(frm: FormGroup) {
    return frm.get('password').value === frm.get('confirmed').value ? null : {'mismatch': true};
  }

}
```

Webstorm doesn't seem to have a problem locating the method:

[image: webstrom-refer-hint]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = new FormGroup({
    ...
  }, {validator: CustomValidator.pwdMatchValidator});
}
```

Comment: can ypu post the whole code you have at this.form=new FormGroup

Comment: Posted. For some reason, the error has gone, but sometimes it appears again. I don't know how to reproduce that problem.